# TFS2012 reflect changes to server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I'm having trouble setting TFS2012 to control project source files between 3-4 people.
I've been googling for 3 days, and now I'm completely lost trying to map local and server folders in workspace. So far I have managed to create a server, a project, and connect to it using Visual Studio 2010.

All I'm trying to achieve is to share one solution between this group of people, lock files for changing, and reflect those changes to server (and therefore to other people in my group) after I check in the file I made changes to...

Can someone explain how to set this up??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workspaces are set up the clients, not the server.

So, in Visual Studio (including Team Explorer if you have only the TFS client without the rest of VS) connect to the TFS instance and select the right team project.

If VS does not immediately prompt you to create a workspace (it's been a while since I did this on a refresh install) go to File | Source Control | Advanced | Workspaces...

There you can select or create a workspace (remember workspaces are specific to the combination of user and computer). Once you open a workspace to edit you can create mappings between source control paths and local paths.

NB. in the workspaces dialogue you can select "Show Remote Workspaces" to see other users' and computers' workspaces and copy mappings to paste into another.